# Charting and Analyzing data

Tags: excel, sharepoint, reporting-services, charts, business-intelligence

I work a lot with SharePoint and wanted to dive deeper into the tools I have available to me in the area of Business Intelligence.

I also recently got a motorcycle, and have created [a spreadsheet to help me calculate the costs of the motorcycle versus the cost of my car](http://1drv.ms/1thV1LF).

I figured this was a good chance to take some real data that is interesting to me and find out from the experts.

How I can use this data in a Chart, SQL reporting, Performance Point, Excel charts, or anything else I may not be thinking of as it relates to my learning objectives? What is the best tool to use to analyse this data better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to stay with excel. No need to export data, connect data etc.  For example select a data range and just press Insert-> Chart. Then play around a little with it. If you get familiar with excel, try to make better tables with calculated cells. In that case you can easy make Pivot tables and pivotcharts. That's all you need for data analyse.

Maybe update the sheet with your weekly spendings, budget, budget vs spending, periods etc. etc.

Even if you will work with huge amounts of data, excel is still your friend.

More data, is more information. For the data you have now, even a chart won't give you extra information or better insight.